# ImportError in Google Cloud Function: cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud'

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've been working on a Google Cloud Function that reads GCP log files and stores them in a bucket. It's written in Python and is deployed via the Google Cloud Console.

1# Here is the main structure of my function located in the main.py:

```
import base64
import json
import os
import uuid
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from google.cloud import storage

# Global variables
BATCH_SIZE = 10  # Number of log entries to write to GCS at once
current_batch_size = 0
tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)

# Function definition
def logs_to_gcs(data, context):
    global current_batch_size, tmp_file
    # Processing and storing log entries
    # ...

# I'm skipping the rest for brevity, but the full function processes logs, writes them to a CSV and uploads it to a GCS bucket.
```

2# I have specified the google-cloud-storage library as a dependency in my requirements.txt file:

```
google-cloud-storage>=1.42.0
```

3# However, when I run the function from the Google Cloud Console, I receive the following ImportError:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

The error seems to occur at the import statement in the main.py script:

```
from google.cloud import storage
```

I'm using the Python 3.10 runtime and I've made sure that the requirements.txt file is in the correct location. I've been trying to troubleshoot this issue for a while now but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and could possibly suggest a solution? Is this a compatibility issue with Python 3.10, or is there a problem with the way I've set up my requirements.txt file or the import statement in the script? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these packages as well to your reqs.txt (would recommend using latest `google.cloud.storage` version)

```
google-api-core==2.11.1 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
google-auth==2.17.3 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
google-cloud-core==2.3.3 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
google-cloud-storage==2.10.0 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
google-crc32c==1.5.0 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
google-resumable-media==2.5.0 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
googleapis-common-protos==1.60.0 ; python_version >= "3.10" and python_version < "4.0"
```

Comment: I had the same problem. This fixed it for me. Can aynone explain why this works and why it didn't work before? I though just adding google-cloud-storage to the requirements should be working fine?